# Python3 OpenSSL binding of RSA_public_decrypt()

Tags: python, cryptography, openssl, rsa

Is there any openssl binding in python 3.4 that binds the function `RSA_public_decrypt()` from libopenssl that allows us to decrypt stuff using a public key? For some reason, I need to do this in a project.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I found this slightly hacky (note the **.hazmat.** imports) solution

```
def do_decrypt_cryptography(message, private_key):
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
    return private_key.decrypt(message,
                               padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()),
                                            algorithm=hashes.SHA1(),
                                            label=None))
```

Comment: if someone else confirms this works (i don't have the time to do it myself, it's an old project), i'll validate the answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the M2Crypto library? It looks like the `M2Crypto.RSA.RSA` class has a `public_decrypt(self, data, padding)` function. M2Crypto is a Python wrapper for OpenSSL, but I'm not sure if that `public_decrypt` function directly calls the C OpenSSL `RSA_public_decrypt()` function. If you go that route, I'd double check the source to make sure.

http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/

Comment: Sorry, I know about m2crypto and I forgot to mention I wanted something python3 compatible. m2crypto is not ported to python3 and no one is really trying to it...

Comment: Ah, sorry, can't help you then. I wonder how difficult it would be to pull just the stuff you need from M2Crypto and make it compatible with Python 3. Probably more trouble than it's worth if I had to guess.